# Unexpected thin line under Bootstrap navtabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Bootstrap3. Very strange thin line under the tab. But not all tabs, the "settings" tab is OK without line underneath.

It only shows the line in firefox. Other browser is fine.

Anyone has the same problem as mine?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="my_account.php"> Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="my_account_settings.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="my_account_credits.php"> Credits</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nav tabs will have a border, from:

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

For the active tab this border (bottom) will be hidden by:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
{
    border-color: #DDDDDD #DDDDDD transparent;
}
```

When you changes this css code, b.e. set the .nav-tabs border to 2px, the active bottom border won't by hidden any more.

**update**

Based on your code (wrapped in a .container div) is see this in FF en Chrome:

[image]

The line under the profile tab in your image is not as expected. Try your code with Bootstrap's css only. Your custom css will change the border color (of the .nav-tabs > li.active > a etc.) maybe?

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I understand. The "transparent" just seems not working on the my active tabs except the second "settings" tab alone. Very stange. I looked up those CSS rules and they are right there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it. The reason for the line was that I had added badges in the nav:

```
<span class="badge">xx</span>
```

To remove the thin line I just added a class "pull-right" to the badges and it worked:

```
<span class="badge pull-right">xx</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem and cannot identify what is wrong with the css, though I'm having it on chrome.  I've noticed that this only happens if I have an icon or img in the tab header.  Do you see this if you remove the icon in your settings tab header?  Try removing that.

Comment: I do have one glyphicon on one tab. My problem has gone now but I don't know how I fix it. Only later two tabs start to use HTTPS to enter. I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem. Or maybe I reordered my javascript/jquery files. The order of them sometimes screw things up.